# InvokeMethod failure: Response is not well-formed XML in load runner

Tags: loadrunner

Imported the WSDL and invoked the 'Add Service Call'. I am getting the output but, When the script is executed, getting the following error message. 
Error: InvokeMethod failure: Response is not well-formed XML..
Error: ExtractResultArg failure: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..

Really appreciate if someone look into this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to solve the specific problem you're having, but I can tell you that when testing web services I have found it far more efficient and useful to test them using the WEB/HTML protocol instead. You can make a web_custom_request() directly to the WSDL URL. Our developers use SOAP UI to unit test the web services and it's a breeze to import the calls created in that tool (there's a free version) into a LR script without a lot of the hassle in the Web Services protocol provided in LR.

Here's an example of how I set it up:

```
// first add whatever headers you need
web_add_header("x-ssl-client-cert","-----CERTIFICATE STRING-----");

// use web_custom_request to invoke web service
// hand code the request or use something like SOAPUI
// to record the request
web_custom_request("Your Web Service Call",
   "Method=POST",
   "URL=http://... ", \\ URL to the WSDL
   "Body=<soapenv:Envelope "
        "xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" "
        "xmlns:mul=\"http://www...\" "
        "xmlns=\"http://www....\"> "
            "   <soapenv:Header/>"
            "   <soapenv:Body>"
            " "                   // body of your request
            "   </soapenv:Body>"
            "</soapenv:Envelope>",
            "TargetFrame=",
    LAST);
```

You may have better luck using this method instead.

Comment: If you have working unit test cases that work from SoapUI, you can create calls in a web-services script using the "Import SOAP" button instead of muddling around with WSDL.

Compared to web_custom_requests, this eliminates a lot of the hand coding and provides nicer UI for looking at requests and responses in a tree view. Also provides mechanisms to corelate and parametrize using xml xpath queries.

Comment: It's been my experience that eliminating "a lot of the hand coding" is rarely a good thing. Losing control of your code to a bunch of back end GUI assembly is just lazy and causes you to lose any real understanding of what your script is actually doing and why, leading to the sort of cryptic errors like the one that started this thread. Keeping the code as pure as possible ensures control over it.